# Conda package, pure but with entry points

Tags: python, setuptools, conda-build

A `noarch` conda recipe seems not to work when being built on Windows, as the entry point gets a wrapper with an `.exe` extension. This makes `conda-build` complain, that the resulting package is not no-arch any more. This makes somehow sense, but the same does not apply on Linux systems, I guess because of the missing extension.

I wonder, if

1. Is there a possibility to still build a `noarch-package` containing entry-points?
2. Is there a workaround creating wrappers without an extension?

The package looks something like this

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
   foo = bar:main
```

So there will be a `foo.exe` contained in the final package on Windows.

Building with `conda-build` results in an error like this:

```
Packaging foo
...
[noarch_python] Noarch package contains binary script: foo.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/2627

The problem is solved, when defining the same entry point in the conda recipe as in setup.py/cfg. This somehow creates a cross-plattform wrapper.